# Customize Payment Option in WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a very basic question. I want to accept a custom payment method in checkout page at WooCommerce. The new custom method will contain a simple text box where client will be able to enter some numbers. Is there a plugin available for that? Or can you guide me how to do that manually? I am using Porto WordPress theme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is a custom payment gateway in Wordpress WooCommerce. There is **Forminator**  and **WooCommerce Custom Payment Gateway** just to mention a few. In your Wordpress backend, go to Plugins> Add New> and type 'Custom Payment' and click search.